# How to make sure an img tag was seen by browser user?

Tags: javascript, css, events, fraud-prevention

Imagine we have two similar images with different sizes in a Webpage which one of them might be hidden by CSS @media rules.

Then i need a proper way or Javascript event to detect that at least one of the images was loaded and **actually seen** by browser client.

My ultimate goal is to detect fraud impression in a website.So i need to make sure at least one of images actually was seen.

My naive implementation is as following:

1. User opens up a web browser
2. User visits a website that contains those images (banners e.g advertisements)
3. Browser requests a banner from a server and displays that image for a user (in this stage i increment impression for that website)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question with examples of your code _ https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is nothing special in my implementation. i need an idea to start.

Answer (score 2):

This is the essence and usefulness of **thumbnails**. It is very difficult to directly ensure that the image is seen - the user may just scroll through your page in a split second without looking at the image or they may actually scroll your image into view but have their attention at something else on the page (like the dashboard) or even have their attention away from the screen.

So, you want to provide thumbnails and when the thumbnail link is clicked, you attach `onload` listeners to the full image on the next page. This is how you know one had interest on your image and actually viewed it. This code illustrates this:

```
<!-- The Full image page --> 
<div id='imageContainer'></div>
<script>
    let imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = 'https://myFullImagelink.com/imageSample.png';
    imgObj.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("imageContainer").appendChild(imgObj);
    }
</script>
```

Now you can observe that on the next page the full image is first loaded before it is visible to the user.

For instance, the revenues from adverts on a page are not earned by the owner when the user simply sees the advert placement but when the user clicks on it and the full view of the advert is successfully loaded.